# Sending Files using Active MQ with BlobMessage

Tags: activemq-classic, spring-jms, jmstemplate

I have an requirement in my application to send files from one application to another over HTTP/FTP protocol. I found following link which tells that the same can be done using Active MQ with supoort of Blob messages:

activemq.apache.org/blob-messages.html

I configured **ActiveMq 5.8** on my windows machine, included required dependency for **ActiveMQ** lib in my `pom.xml` and i am able to send the simple `javax.jms.TextMessage` and `javax.jms.MapMessage` with `org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate`

But while i moved to send BlobMessage using following method, a compile time error arises while creating the  `BlobMessage` object from `javax.jms.Session` object which says

> The method createBlobMessage(File) is undefined for the type Session

Here is the method i am using:

```
public void sendFile(){


        jmsTemplate.send(
        new MessageCreator() {
          public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {


              BlobMessage message = session.createBlobMessage(new File("/foo/bar"));
              return jmsTemplate.send(message);
          }
        }


);
}
```

Please help to resolve this compile time error.

Regards,

Arun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BlobMessage methods are not JMS spec methods so they won't appear in the javax.jms.Session interface, you need to cast to org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession in order to use the BlobMessage specific functionality.

Comment: You are right. By type casting, i am able to create the `BlobMessage` from session instance. Can you tell how can i send this blob message with some `producer` instance as i am unable to send the newly created blog message  with JMSTemplate. It would be good if you provide some sample code to send the blob message using Spring itself.