# Sending a BlobMessage using JmsTemplate with CachingConnectionFactory

Tags: java, spring, session, activemq-classic, jmstemplate

I am using ActiveMQ as my message broker and I have a JMS requirement of sending a big document as an input stream to be processed by consumers. The issue I have is that if I use Spring's org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory to wrap an ActiveMQConnectionFactory, I'll have to cast the session object (javax.jms.Session) into an org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession which is what was suggested in here ([Sending Files using Active MQ with BlobMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17550112/sending-files-using-active-mq-with-blobmessage)).

I then get an exception if I cast the generic Session object into an ActiveMQSession because Spring only provides a Proxy for the javax.jms.Session and not the target object that it proxies to (ie org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession). So the solution I resorted to was to just use a plain ActiveMQConnectionFactory instead of using a CachingConnectionFactory. Is there a way for me to keep a CachingConnectionFactory without getting the ClassCastException from my sample code below?

```
  jmsTemplate.send(new MessageCreator() {
    public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
      org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession activeMQSession = ((org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession) session);

      BlobMessage message = activeMQSession.createBlobMessage(inputStream);
      LOGGER.debug("created a blob message");
      return message;
    }
  });
```

And here's what I currently have now in my application context which will prevent the ClassCastException from being thrown. See the commented blocks as well which shows the old configuration I have which throws the exception:

```
<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
  <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
  <property name="defaultDestination" ref="gtJobRequestQueue"/>
</bean>

<!--   <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory"> -->
<!--     <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="activeMqConnectionFactory" /> -->
<!--     <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="3"/> -->
<!--     <property name="cacheProducers" value="true"/> -->
<!--   </bean> -->

<!-- <bean id="activeMqConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.spring.ActiveMQConnectionFactory"> -->
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.spring.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
  <property name="brokerURL" value="${aurin.data-provider.broker.url}"/>
  <property name="prefetchPolicy" ref="prefetchPolicy" /> 
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

SessionProxy sp = (SessionProxy)session;

ActiveMQSession as = (ActiveMQSession)sp.getTargetSession();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).